# Leaflet / JS Removing Layer with Variable

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am attempting to remove a layer (I am using a self made UI with a dropdown menu here!)

When I attempt to have a layer removed using this code: `setTimeout(function() {map.removeLayer(mapid); });` I do not get an error but it does nothing.  I can see in the console that the value is populated properly.

If I replace the mapid here with one of the map names like: `setTimeout(function() {map.removeLayer(basicmap); });` it will remove this layer.  I am trying to find a better way to do this than add 35 remove options!

Anyone have any ideas or suggestion as to what would be preventing the layer from removing?

```
var mapselect = "basicmap";
var mapid = "basicmap";
function scheduleA(event) {
mapselect = this.value;
console.log("map value: " + mapselect);
//Remove Everything
console.log("map id: " + mapid);
setTimeout(function() {map.removeLayer(mapid); });

if (mapselect == "basicmap") { 
setTimeout(function() {basicmap.addTo(map); });
console.log('option 0');
}
//change the map id to be hard coded here and go back to option 1,2,3,4,5,etc
if (mapselect == "outpost1") { 
setTimeout(function() {outpost1.addTo(map); });
console.log('option 1');
}

if (mapselect == "recoverymap") {
setTimeout(function() {recoverymap.addTo(map); });
console.log('option 2');
}

if (mapselect == "reconmap") {
setTimeout(function() {reconmap.addTo(map); });
console.log('option 3');
}

if (mapselect == "exmap") { 
setTimeout(function() {exmap.addTo(map); });
console.log('option 4');
}
console.log(mapselect);
mapid = mapselect;

}
```

For reference here is the HTML code calling the function:

```
                    <label for="Map">Choose a Mission:</label>
                        <select name="Map" id="Map" onchange="scheduleA.call(this, event)">
                          <option value="basicmap" selected></option>
                          <option value="outpost1">Map 1</option>
                          <option value="recoverymap">Map 2</option>
                          <option value="reconmap">Map 3</option>
                          <option value="exmap">Map 4</option>
                        </select><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `setTimeout` it will force that `map.removeLayer(mapid);` is called at the end of your function `scheduleA`. Before the timeout is executed you overwrite the mapid with the new selected map. So when the remove is called you remove the new added layer -> which results that it looks like nothing happend (but it added the new one and removed it again)

I don't know why you use `setTimeout`, you can remove it, it is nowhere needed

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you must keep your `setTimeout`'s, simply reverse the way you are handling your current and new values of `mapid`, by having instead the *previous* and "new current" values:

```js
const previousMapid = mapid;

// Remove the previous
setTimeout(() => map.removeLayer(previousMapid));

// Now you can safely re-assign mapid
mapid = this.value;
```